# R - Remove rows that have != n occurrences

Tags: r

I would like to remove the rows that does not happen `n`-times. So, if my factor variable happens `!= n` times, I want to drop all the factor-variables of that kind.

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame( 
  my_factor = factor(rep(1:24, each = 10)),
  value     = runif(240, min = -10, max = 125)
)
# Each factor appears 10 times

# Adding a row, that makes my_factor == 23 appear 11 times
x <- data.frame(
  my_factor = 23, 
  value = 100)

df <- rbind(df, c(23, 100))
```

Now I would like to see how many occurrences there are of my `my_factor`, and be able to remove all the rows where the number of occurrences differ from `n`.

In the data example, I want to drop all factor variables equal to 23.

I've tried attacking it with `rle`, but I can't seem to use it with subset

```
y <- rle(as.character(df$my_factor))
y$lengths != 10

df[y$lengths != 10, ] # Wrong output
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `table` instead:

```
table(df$my_factor) != 10
# 
#     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
#    23    24 
#  TRUE FALSE 
names(which(table(df$my_factor) != 10))
# [1] "23"
df[!df$my_factor %in% names(which(table(df$my_factor) != 10)), ]
```

---

`ave` can also be used:

```
df[ave(1:nrow(df), df$my_factor, FUN = length) == 10, ]
```

Or, with "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, N := .N, by = my_factor][N == 10]
```

Comment: Is there a way in `data.table` to subset on `.N` immediately (without first creatin `N := .N`)?

Comment: `setDT(df)[,.SD[.N==10,], by=my_factor]` may be this

Comment: @Ananda Mahto.  It should be slow.  Not sure if this is faster `df1 <- setDT(df)[df[,.I[.N==10], by=my_factor]$V1,]`

Answer (score 1):

You basically had it, but needed to sort the factors for a correct rle:

```
 y <- rle(as.character(sort(df$my_factor))) #sort!
```

and then

```
 df[df$my_factor %in% y$values[y$lengths != 10], ]
```

or

```
 df[df$my_factor %in% y$values[y$lengths == 10], ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tt = (table(df$my_factor)!=10)

df[df$my_factor == names(tt)[which(tt)],]

    my_factor       value
221        23  26.8138067
222        23  -2.8933233
223        23  34.9496288
224        23  39.8694566
225        23  -5.3975642
226        23  46.7891582
227        23   0.9553145
228        23  -5.8235961
229        23  64.8645187
230        23  22.3176873
241        23 100.0000000
> 
# For other rows:
head(df[df$my_factor != names(tt)[which(tt)],])
  my_factor      value
1         1  26.863197
2         1   6.200210
3         1   7.474887
4         1  -3.015083
5         1  65.889539
6         1 111.526084
>
```